# Tensorflow in RStudio Error - 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement'

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, rstudio

I would be eternally grateful if someone could help me identify what is going wrong, I have been working on this for a few days.

I am trying to use Tensorflow within RStudio (I have used it many times before without any issues).
I am using Anaconda 64 bit version and have tried Python versions 3.9.18, 3.11.5 and 3.12.0 with no luck.

Currently, when I check my python configeration, I get the below output:

```
reticulate::py_config() 
python:        C:/Users/cow4575/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/python.exe 
libpython:     C:/Users/cow4575/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/python39.dll 
pythonhome:    C:/Users/cow4575/.conda/envs/tf-gpu 
version:        3.9.18 (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:30:38) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:         C:/Users/cow4575/.conda/envs/tf-gpu/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.26.0 
tensorflow:    C:\Users\cow4575\CONDA~1\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.p
NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python() function
```

No matter what I do I cannot seem to get Tensorflow to play ball and keep getting the below error:

`Error: Valid installation of TensorFlow not found.`

OR

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.12.* (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.12.*`

I have also tried downloading & calling different versions of Tensorflow (2.13, 2.14 etc) with no luck - I still get the same error.

I am using a work computer which has permission restrictions when it comes to installing software, is this likely to be the issue?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

I have tried using different Python versions, different working environments, different Tensorflow versions and have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda. None of this has helped, I still get the same errors.

Comment: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow` looks like this is the output of a `pip install` command. Might be an issue of `pip` not being able to connect to PyPi through your work network. Are you able to install any module with `pip`?